# Toggle between 2 divs - visibility and css animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

In my site, I have two divs within a container. One div has text in English and the other has text in mandarin I have a button on the side that I want the user to toggle and control the visibility of each div/language they are comfortable with. I'm using JS to add/remove class visibility (opacity and display). By default, I have the English one in view. My sketch works halfway, when a user clicks the button, the English div fades but the mandarin one doesn't appear. Code below-

HTML -

```
 <div class="textSection">

            <div class="eng about" id="eng">
               <p>SHEK LEUNG
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="mandarin about" id="man">
               <p>
                  「為Samson畢業後在倫敦創立的品牌
               </p>
            </div>
         </div>
         <button class="langChange">⥃</button>
```

css -

```
.textSection {

   width: 50vw;
   height: 80vh;
   position: relative;
   top: 10vh;
   left: 30vw;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;

}



.about {

   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   opacity: 1;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   transition: all 1s;

}

.eng {
   border-radius: 10px;
   background: url("72ppi/Asset\ 3.png");
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 1.2rem;
   line-height: 1.7;
   text-align: justify;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   color: white;
   padding: 3rem;
   opacity: 1;
   display: block;

}

.mandarin {

   font-family: Hiragino Sans GB;
   font-size: 1.3rem;
   line-height: 2;
   text-align: justify;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: black;
   padding: 3rem;
   opacity: 1;
   border-radius: 10px;
   border: solid 2px black;
   opacity: 0;
   display: none;
}

.hidden {
   display: none;
}

.visuallyhidden {
   opacity: 0;
}

.seen {
   display: block;
}

.visual {
   opacity: 1;
}
.langChange {
   position: absolute;
   border: none;
   padding: 1rem 2rem;
   border-radius: 10px;
   margin: 0;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 2rem;
   left: 20vw;
   cursor: pointer;
   background-color: transparent;
   color: black;
   
}
```

JS -

```
let engBox = document.getElementById('eng'),
   manBox = document.getElementById('man')
langbtn = document.querySelector('.langChange');

langbtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
   console.log(engBox.classList);
   if (engBox.classList.contains('hidden')) {
      engBox.classList.remove('hidden');
      setTimeout(function () {
         engBox.classList.remove('visuallyhidden');
      }, 20);
   } else {
      engBox.classList.add('visuallyhidden');
      engBox.addEventListener('transitionend', function (e) {
         engBox.classList.add('hidden');
      }, {
         capture: false,
         once: true,
         passive: false
      });
   }

}, false);

langbtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
   console.log(manBox.classList);
   if (manBox.classList.contains('seen')) {
      manBox.classList.remove('seen');
      setTimeout(function () {
         manBox.classList.remove('visual');
      }, 20);
   } else {
      manBox.classList.add('seen');
      manBox.addEventListener('transitionend', function (e) {
         manBox.classList.add('seen');
      }, {
         capture: false,
         once: true,
         passive: false
      });
   }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Start simple and build up. Here is a minimal working visibility toggle. Position changes, layout, and most timing can be added to the CSS piece by piece until you have what you want.

```js
const engBox = document.getElementById('eng');
const manBox = document.getElementById('man');
const langbtn = document.querySelector('.langChange');

langbtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
   engBox.classList.toggle('transparent');
   manBox.classList.toggle('transparent');
});
```

```css
.about {
overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 2s;
}

.transparent {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="textSection">

  <div class="eng about" id="eng">
    <p>SHEK LEUNG
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="mandarin about transparent" id="man">
    <p>
      「為Samson畢業後在倫敦創立的品牌
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="langChange">⥃</button>
</div>
```